# Does 指鹿为马 = Don't pee on my leg and tell me it's raining?

Tags: translation, usage

I'm teaching idioms to university students in China. I wonder if 指鹿为马 could be used as a translation / explanation of "Don't pee on my leg and tell me it's raining." Yeah, that's not a high-frequency idiom, but I like to throw in some fun ones every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

"The Emperor's New Clothes" is a story that is close to the story of 指鹿为马.

Comment: The similarity is 'telling the truth will cause you trouble' the story of 指鹿为马 is more sinister, it was a plot  to weed out the opposition by a powerful minister who wished to marginalize the king and grab power for himself, meanwhile 'The Emperor's New Clothes' focus on the foolishness of the emperor

Comment: The main character in the story "The Emperor's New Clothes" is the boy who tells the truth. In the story of 指鹿为马, it is all about the intrigues of all the characters.

Answer (score 0):

指鹿为马 (calling a deer a horse) means "brazenly twisting facts"

"pee on someone's leg and tell him it's raining." would be more accurate.

A good example would be saying "military assault rifles are not responsible for the high fatality rate in mass shootings!"

Answer (score 0):

While 指鹿为马 does mean the act of "twisting facts", the real, or most important, lesson is the sarcasm of people upholding(附合) the absurd(荒謬/顛倒黑白) claim made by the person who has unchangeable power over their fate/future(權勢).

Your story does have the absurdity but lacks the detail of a crowd agreeing with the absurd claim due to fear/greed, therefore, IMO, a misuse of the idiom.

Answer (score 0):

It is a metaphor of political correctness.